# What is the basic difference between maven compiler plugin and maven surefire plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

What is the basic difference between maven compiler plugin and maven surefire plugin?

Also, I wanted to define system variables inside the pom.xml, under plugin configuration and read it from my java code(Using System.property()).

```
<configuration>
   <systemPropertyVariables>
       <envName>testEnv</envName>
   </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
```

This configuration is working with maven surefire plugin and I am able to read it in my java file, however, same is not working with maven compiler plugin.

Comment: Giving system properties to the Java program you compile cannot work. The program accesses those values _at runtime_, so that they depend on the environment you run in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are two different plugins.

maven-compiler-plugin, as its name suggests, handles compiling your code.

maven-surefire-plugin handles [unit] test execution and failing the build process if there are test failures.